# Sequelize.js min and max length validator are not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js, sequelize.js

I am trying to validate `min` and `max` validations through model validations

```
last_name:{
            type:Sequelize.STRING,
            validate:{
                notEmpty:{
                    args:true,
                    msg:"Last name required"
                },
                is:{
                    args:["^[a-z]+$",'i'],
                    msg:"Only letters allowed in last name"
                },
                max:{
                    args:32,
                    msg:"Maximum 32 characters allowed in last name"
                },
                min:{
                    args:4,
                    msg:"Minimum 4 characters required in last name"
                }
            }
        }
```

But the `min` and `max` validators are never fired all other validators are working fine

Answer (score 9):

You need to pass args an array

```
    max:{
         args:[32],
         msg:"Maximum 32 characters allowed in last name"
   },
   min:{
        args:[4],
        msg:"Minimum 4 characters required in last name"
   }
```

With use of len validator:

```
var Test = sequelize.define('test', {
     name: {
         type: Sequelize.STRING,
         validate: {
             notEmpty: {
                 args: true,
                 msg: "Required"
            },
            is: {
                args: ["^[a-z]+$", 'i'],
                msg: "Only letters allowed"
            },
            len: {
                args: [4,32],
                msg: "String length is not in this range"
           }
       }
    },
    id: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        primaryKey: true,
        autoIncrement: true
   }
}, {
tableName: 'test'
});        

  Test.create({name: "ab"}, function(error, result) {});
```

Comment: You can use len validator with args as [4,32]

Comment: max and min will check the values. As you have string, you have to write custom validator with max/min to check number of characters

Comment: If you use max and min validator, it validates given value i.e. in your case, it checks whether given value is less than equal to 32 or greater than equal to 4.

Comment: `min` and `max` are  undefined rules! but `len` works